# exclude some rows from my outer join result set

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

i have one table called products and the other one called prices.

Now i am trying to to show all products with and without prices, so i am using a left join. So far so good.

```
select * from products,prices where products.id = prices.id(+)
```

The prices table does also have a **validFrom** and a **validTo** record. What i want to achieve now is to **exclude** the expired records(first two rows). Is this possible when i am using left join

this is the result of the query.

ResultSet:
[image: ResultSet]

With

```
SELECT *
FROM   products
       LEFT JOIN prices
            ON   products.id = prices.id
                 AND (prices.validfrom >= sysdate
                      OR prices.validfrom IS NULL)
                 AND (prices.validto < sysdate
                      OR prices.validto IS NULL);
```

I get
 [image]

expected result however should be:
[image]

Comment: In your expected result Table and Chair are missing. But that are products in `products` aren't they? So a left join includes them. To exclude them you maybe want an inner join instead (change `LEFT` to `INNER`). But that changes the premises of the question.

Comment: okay - i think i get it now. Just one more question: if a add another where clause to the actual one below where i only want to show the product "Laptop", why i am still getting 7 rows?

Comment: Actually you should get any other records than those for Laptop then. But I cannot tell without knowing the actual query... But before this question totally mutates, I'd recommend you ask a new question regarding this issue and show your query with the additional condition in the `WHERE` there.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. PS You might want a where after joining. But please give a description in words of how your desired output is a function of your input--not just an example. Please read & act on [mcve]. Including cut & paste & runnable text/input/output.

Comment: can you show us  the table with column names  so that i can figure out which one is joining column???

Comment: @stickybit & SassaMoustafa Please do not inline images that should be inline text. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Anyway a [mcve] should have cut & paste & runnable input/code/output.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check, that `prices.validfrom <= sysdate AND prices.validto > sysdate` to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT *
       FROM products
            LEFT JOIN prices
                      ON products.id = prices.id
                         AND (prices.validfrom <= sysdate
                               OR prices.validfrom IS NULL)
                         AND (prices.validto > sysdate
                               OR prices.validto IS NULL);
```

You should also use the explicit `LEFT JOIN` syntax instead of that ancient `WHERE ... (+)` thing.

Comment: For some reason if i do it like that, i am now getting 7 rows where only data from my left row are displayed and nothing from the prices table at all. The result should be 5 rows, right?

Comment: @SassaMoustafa: Hmm, I forgot to handle the cases when the validity dates are null. But that wouldn't cause more data to be shown, rather less. Anyway, please consider to post sample data and the desired result with that sample data to clarify.

Comment: @SassaMoustafa: I guess Gordon (Thanks!) got it right, I confused the comparisons' directions... Try it again.

Comment: yes - i know that null values has to be handled(did a nvl for that). If think about it again, my goal was not to show the expired prices so it not should be filtered against them(because they are expired). Are there just 7 rows because of the left join?

Comment: @SassaMoustafa: All what is in the left table of a `LEFT JOIN` is in the result, even if the condition doesn't match. So, if you got 7 products you'll get (at least) 7 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from products,prices where products.id = prices.id(+)) WHERE (prices.validTo IS NULL OR prices.validTo > sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you will better have to use inner join for it not left outer join;